# Convert universal quantification to existential quantification

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I came across following problem

"Every intelligent student is not honest."

And I have to convert this in quantifiers. Straight conversion will be:

∀x [(S(x)∧I(x)) → ¬H(x)]    ...(i)

However the solution is given in existential quantifier as follows:

∃x [S(x)∧I(x)∧¬H(x)]        ...(ii)

with explanation "There exist intelligent students who are not honest"

Though this sounds and looks correct, how can I convert (i) to (ii) mathematically I mean without verbal interpretation, may be by double negation?

Comment: What if there are no students?

Comment: I think the given solution is incorrect. It appears to conflate “Every intelligent student is not honest” and “Not every intelligent student is honest”.

Comment: The two sentences are not equivalent. Are you sure you're not misunderstanding what the problem asks for?

Comment: What are the dots standing in for? Is that the whole sentence?

Comment: @GFauxPas those are just "refer this as" (i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the above comments, the given solution is not correct.

From :

> $∀x [(S(x) \land I(x)) \rightarrow \lnot H(x)]$

we have to start using the equivalence between $\forall$ and $\lnot \exists \lnot$ to get

> $\lnot \exists x \lnot [(S(x) \land I(x)) \rightarrow \lnot H(x)]$.

Then, we have to apply the *tautological equivalence* between : $\lnot (p \rightarrow \lnot q)$ and $(p \land q)$ [you can check it with a truth-table] and convert the above formula into :

> > $\lnot \exists x [S(x) \land I(x) \land H(x)]$.

Comment: can we get this by double negation: `¬¬∀x[(S(x)∧I(x))→¬H(x)]` ≡ `¬∃x¬[(S(x)∧I(x))→¬H(x)]` ≡ `¬∃x[(S(x)∧I(x))∧H(x)]` (Since `¬(p→q)≡p∧¬q`) ≡ `¬∃x[S(x)∧I(x)∧H(x)]`

Comment: @awellwisher - yes : $\lnot \forall$ is $\exists \lnot$; thus $\lnot \lnot \forall$ is $\lnot \exists \lnot$.